# How to generate .html file using JavaScript/HTML/PHP?

Tags: javascript, html

For a student project, I am creating a web interface for business.

Among other things, I want the employees to be allowed to download a standardized email signature, which will be generated automatically, with their personal information.

I know how to create a .txt file with Javascript, but I don't know to create a .html file.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Exactly the same, but instead of saving it as a `.txt`, you save it as a `.html`?

Comment: "I know how to create a .txt file with Javascript, but I don't know to create a .html file." — The same way. HTML is text.

Comment: Okay yes, I'm dumb, just a mistake in my code. Thank you ! have a nice day!

Comment: @Jeremy No need to apologize. There would not be much use for Stackoverflow without mistakes :) Please consider deleting this question, if it's no longer relevant.